# How to change header color (contextPopupMenuStyle)

Tags: java, android, attributes

I want to change the header color of(title)

the content color is changed by `itemTextAppearance` attribute.

how to change header, title color?

`contextPopupMenuStyle` attribute is supported API 24. Please help!

Comment: What research have you done?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I dont know how do this in xml files, but you can do this programmicaly from code by using SpannableString in onCreateContextMenu.

For example :

```
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString("my_string"));
spannableString.setSpan(new FregroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#D1BA88")), 0, spannableString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    menu.setHeaderTitle(spannableString);
```